# Can unformatted partitions have UUIDs?

Tags: linux, partition, block-device

Can a partition have a UUID without a filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

Partitions are identified by uuid on the newer `gpt` partition table (compare to `msdos` partition tables which do not have uuids). In Linux `gpt` partitions also show up in `/dev/disk/by-partuuid`.

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit? The answer is - YES, if it is a GPT partition, NO if not?

Comment: msdos partitions do not have uuids, gpt partitions do. Normally this doesn't matter though, because you just identify the partition you want by the uuid of its filesystem.